# Run 2 actions simultaneously? Game freezes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Alright, so I've tried a few different things here and nothing is working. 
I have a dozen sprite nodes that each need to:

1. wait for a delay
2. repeat this forever:

a. move down the screen WHILE scaling to a bigger size (i.e. these 2 happen simultaneously)

b. THEN move up the screen WHILE scaling back to original size (these happen simultaneously also)

Normally I thought this would work with a sequence and grouping the scaling and moving actions in 2 blocks, but it hasn't worked. The following gets the node to do it **once**:

```
 block1.runAction(SKAction.runBlock({
            self.block1.runAction(moveDownLeft)
            self.block1.runAction(scaleBlock)
            let nodelay = 0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            let notime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(nodelay))
            //during delay
            dispatch_after(notime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                //after delay
                self.block1.runAction(moveUpLeft)
                self.block1.runAction(scaleBlockBack)
            }
        })
        )
```

but when I introduce the `repeatActionForever`, the whole game freezes.

Why am I not able to loop the existing code forever? How can I run the 2 actions simultaneously?

Comment: I'm presuming that SpriteKit's `runAction` and `runBlock` aren't automatically asynchronous?  I don't know though; I've not really written any SK apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big issue you are having is the block does not wait. It just runs the code. So what is happening is you are starting the actions it hits the end of the block and because you are doing repeat forever it calls it again even though the actions are not finished. This is causing that block to be called as fast as it can.

I am not entirely sure where you want the delay but something like this should work or get you started in the right direction.

```
let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(4.0) //whatever your delay is

let scaleDownGroup = SKAction.group([moveDownLeft, scaleBlock])
let scaleUpGroup = SKAction.group([moveUpLeft, scaleBlockBack])

let sequence = SKAction.sequence([scaleDownGroup, delay, scaleUpGroup])

let repeat = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)

self.block1.runAction(repeat)
```

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

- `SKAction.group(_:)` runs several SKActions in parallel.
- `SKAction.waitForDuration(_:)` makes a delay.

Use a combination of these to generate your desired effect. Your `dispatch_after` call is the problem, although I'm not sure what exactly.